# How do you calculate for font pairing?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

What is the qualification for a good font pairing? Regardless of the application, what makes a good font pair?

For example, a company has a standard (single) font used in a brand.

Let's say the base font is Rubik (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rubik)

- What is the qualification to find the font pair that would match this base font?
- Which of these two fonts, Poppins or Montserrat would be the technical pair for the base font?

Answer (score 7):

There's no formula....

Whatever the designer feels works well, and suits the target audience, or message, is the deciding factor.

You can't force scientific calculations upon **aesthetic** choices. You may feel a font pairing is fantastic while I may disagree entirely. Just as you may feel using blue is appropriate when I feel green would be better.

Even in your link.. clicking the "Pairings" Option *specifically* reads "**POPULAR** pairing", indicating pairing suggestions are merely based upon the *preference* of users.